# Google Cloud: Export Project and import in another account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, teslamate

I have a project (Teslamate) running on a VM with Docker and a Disk for the data. This is running on a workspace account on google cloud platform and it seems that I can not transfer it to my gmail account without an organisation.

So I'm asking myself how to transfer the project. Should I recreate it on my other google account and try to export and import the data? The data contains driving stats of my car for the last two years. How can I export and import? Can I just copy the files to my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions:

- Keep the same project and only transfert the ownership (if you can, you can also attach the current project to another organisation for instance, your personal one)
- Export the data/config and import them in another project. For that, you can create an image of your current VM and grant the correct permission on it. On the target project, create a VM with the image that you created. [More detail here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images)

Comment: I tried the first and deleted the original ownership but it still shows up in the original workspace.

Comment: Because the project is attached to an organisation. You can change that attachement, (if you have the permissions) to your own organisation (you just need a domain name for that) https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#perform_migration

Comment: my goal is to run it for free, that's why I want to shut down the organisation. And removing an organisation needs customer support. So I think the best option is to export the data